# Toggle class after initial load in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I have v-for loop where I iterate over some clients and display some data. Inside this loop I have an element that needs to be styled initially based on the client data but on click this has to be toggled between true of false.

```
<div v-for='client in clients'>
   <span class='heart margin-right-10'>
      <i v-bind:class='[client.favourite?"fas fa-heart fa-lg hearted":"fal fa-heart fa-lg"]' v-on:click='change()'></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

So initially `client.favourite` has a value of `true`, and on click this needs to be toggled between true or false.
How should I approach this so I can toggle between the two classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understand your goal I will try with something as simple as possible like:

```
change() {
    client.favourite = !client.favourite;
}
```

Comment: I'm so embarrassed something this simple works. I just didn't know that I could actually change the `client.favourite` after that initial load. Good to know for the future!

Comment: @Otonel don't be, sometimes if the solution is too simple you miss it... And do not forget to accept the answer if this is the case